# How to find line where error occurred in Mathematica notebook?

Tags: debugging, wolfram-mathematica

I have a Mathematica file called myUsefulFunctions.m containing, for example, a function called mySuperUsefulFunction. Suppose I call mySuperUsefulFunction in a notebook and get the following error:

```
Part::pspec: Part specification #1 is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
```

Is there a way to find the line in myUsefulFunctions.m where this error occurred?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know of a way to find the line in the file, which I assume was read without error.

You can however use `Trace` and related functions to see where in the evaluation chain the error occurs.

Example:

```
myFunc1[x_, y_] := x[[y]]
myFunc2[a_List, n_] := Pick[a, a, myFunc1[a, n]]

myFunc2[Range@10, #1]

During evaluation of In[4]:= Part::pspec: Part specification #1 is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
```

With `Trace`:

```
myFunc2[Range@10, #1] // Trace // Column

{Range[10], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
myFunc2[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, #1]
Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, myFunc1[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, #1]]
{myFunc1[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, #1], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}[[#1]], {Message[Part::pspec, #1], {MakeBoxes[Part::pspec: Part specification #1 is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>, StandardForm], RowBox[{RowBox[{Part, ::, "pspec"}], : , "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"Part specification \\\"\",  \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\!\(#1\),  \"MT\"]\)\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\" is neither an integer nor a list of integers.\\\"\",  \"MT\"]\) \!\(\*ButtonBox[\">>\",  ButtonStyle->\"Link\",  ButtonFrame->None,  ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/message/General/pspec\",  ButtonNote -> \"Part::pspec\"]\)"}]}, Null}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}[[#1]]}
```

You can see that just before `Message[Part::pspec, #1]` is called, which results in a long mess of formatting, we had:

`{myFunc1[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, #1], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}[[#1]]`

This shows that `myFunc1[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, #1]` is called, and this causes evaluation of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}[[#1]]` which is clearly in error.

Please see this question and its answers for a more convenient use of `Trace`:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5459735/618728

Comment: Forgot to congratulate you with becoming the third person in the world to get the Mathematica gold badge. Way to go!

Comment: I join Sjoerd - my most sincere congrats! Well - deserved, and long anticipated. Welcome to the club :)

Comment: @Sjoerd thank you very much!  You'd surely have beaten me to it if you didn't have other engagements.

Comment: @Mr. `"My " <> Sequence @@ #@# &@"congrats!"`

Comment: @belisarius You should've used infix.

Comment: @Leonid I can't. You never finished your answer :)

Answer (score 21):

#### A light-weight debug function

In addition to other suggestions, here is a function which helped me a few times:

```
ClearAll[debug];
SetAttributes[debug, HoldAll];
debug[code_] :=
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
   Module[{inMessage},
     Unprotect[Message];        
     Message[args___] /; ! MatchQ[First[Hold[args]], _$Off] :=
       Block[{inMessage = True},
         Print[{
            Shallow /@ Replace[#, HoldForm[f_[___]] :> HoldForm[f], 1],
            Style[Map[Short, Last[#], {2}], Red]
           } &@Drop[Drop[Stack[_], -7], 4]
         ];
         Message[args];
         Throw[$Failed, Message];
       ] /; ! TrueQ[inMessage];
    Protect[Message];
   ];
   Catch[StackComplete[code], Message]]
```

This basically redefines `Message` temporarily to walk up the execution stack and print the names of called functions in an easy to understand form, plus the final call which resulted in an error message, and an error message itself. After that, we exit the execution via exception, to not generated confusing chains of error messages.

#### Examples of use

Here is how this works on an example from @Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
In[211]:= debug[myFunc2[Range@10,#1]]

During evaluation of In[211]:= 
    {{myFunc2,Pick,myFunc1,Part},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}[[#1]]}

During evaluation of In[211]:= Part::pspec: Part specification #1 is neither 
 an integer nor a list of integers. >>

Out[211]= $Failed
```

(in the notebook the problematic function call is painted red). This allows one to quickly see the chain of function calls which lead to the problem.

Here is another example: we construct a custom `gatherBy` function which gathers elements in a list according to another list of "marks", which is supposed to be the same length as the original:

```
listSplit[x_, lengths_] := 
   MapThread[Take[x, {##}] &, {Most[#], Rest[#] - 1}] &@
      Accumulate[Prepend[lengths, 1]];

gatherBy[lst_, flst_] := 
    listSplit[lst[[Ordering[flst]]], (Sort@Tally[flst])[[All, 2]]];
```

For example:

```
In[212]:= gatherBy[Range[10],{1,1,2,3,2,4,5,5,4,1}]
Out[212]= {{1,2,10},{3,5},{4},{6,9},{7,8}}
```

Because I intentionally left all type-checking out, calls with arguments of wrong types will result in chains of nasty error messages:

```
In[213]:= gatherBy[Range[10],Range[15]]//Short
  During evaluation of In[206]:= Part::partw: Part 11 of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} does not exist. >>

  (* 4 more messages here *)
Out[213]//Short= {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},<<14>>}
```

Using `debug`, we can see what's wrong pretty quickly:

```
In[214]:= debug[gatherBy[Range[10],Range[15]]]

 During evaluation of In[214]:= 
    {{gatherBy,listSplit,Part},
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}[[Ordering[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}]]]}

 During evaluation of In[214]:= Part::partw: Part 11 of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} does not exist. >>

 Out[214]= $Failed
```

Calling  `gatherBy[Range[10], a]` with some symbolic `a` is another example where wrapping `debug` around helps.

#### Applicability

The other suggested methods are more systematic and probably more generally recommended, but this one is easy to apply and leads to results which are often easier to understand (e.g. compared to the output of `Trace`, which is not always easy to read). I did not use it as often as to guarantee that it always works, however.

Comment: I know I've said this before, but you really are the resident *Mathematica* professor.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is a gross overestimation, but thanks anyways :) But in fact, in this particular case I hesitated to post `debug`, because I am not fully sure that it always works, and debugging tools must be flawless. Then I thought - the only way to improve it is to post it and get feedback from others, so I did.

Comment: I often put the results of Trace in `TableForm`. Since the results are usually (always?) a list of `{expr, value}` pairs, TableForm helps a bunch.  Try `Trace@Cases[{f[{a, b}], f[{a}], g[{a}], f[{a, b, c, d}]}, 
   f[x_] :> Length@x] // TableForm` versus `Trace@Cases[{f[{a, b}], f[{a}], g[{a}], f[{a, b, c, d}]}, 
   f[x_] -> Length@x] // TableForm`

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Well, so far this just  gives a list of heads called on the way to the problematic one, so it is just a list. I have been thinking to extend this so that it can optionally give more information. I can imagine that something like `TableForm` would then be quite useful.

Answer (score 20):

Apart from the debugger in the Workbench there's also a debugger built-in in Mathematica. You can find it in the Evaluation menu. It is not well documented and rather difficult/unconventional to get it to work. Here is a step-by-step instruction how to use it:

Assuming you have the debugger switched on in the Evaluation menu your window bar will indicate it's a debug session and you will have a few debugger palettes.

[image]

Now select a number of lines you want to act as breakpoints and click on the "break at selection" text. Breakpoints will be marked by a red outline.

[image]

and run the code by pressing Shift-return and be prepared for a slight disappointment: it doesn't work. It appears you cannot define breakpoints on the line level. It must be at function level. Also, MMA is rather picky about the functions you can use. The `Print` function apparently doesn't work neither do assignments. However, the `Integrate` in this example does, but you have to select its head and both brackets and make *that* a breakpoint. If you have done that and you then execute the block of code you get this:

[image]

The breakpoint is highlighted green, some additional options in the control palette have come available to control further program flow, and there are expressions in the stack window. The rest is more or less similar to a standard debugger. Note that you can *nest* breakpoints like the Cos in the Integrate. For a language that can have deeply nested structures this is essential.

---

Another option would be David Bailey's debugger. He offers the free debugger [DebugTrace](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/debugtrace/debugtrace.html) on his website. I haven't tried it myself but I know David as a very capable Mathematica expert so I trust it must be good.

Comment: I believe I've figured out the correct way for setting break point, have a look at here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119916/1871

Answer (score 8):

You can use the WolframWorkbench and the debugger there:

http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/workbench/debugging/

you can then set a break point and step through the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I find Workbench to be a pretty unsatisfactory product. Eclipse is buggy as-is, and plugging Mathematica-functionality on top of it didn't help :( I now do my work in vim, and find my own ways of debugging things...

Comment: Workbench requires a separate license, doesn't it?